# state is null after setting state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component in react that is a simple form, I have a function that looks if there is a change in any of the form elements and then sets the state of the form element being edited. In the handleChange function when I do console.log(this.state) I see the exact thing I expect, the correct keys eg (name, teamName etc) with the values in I have entered in the form.

However when I click submit and it calls the function nextStep I get an error message saying this.state.name is null, am I missing something here?

Here is my component.

```
var ReactDom = require('react-dom');
const uuid = require('uuid/v1');
import {postDataTest} from "../actions/postData";
import TeamSelectBox from "./TeamSelectBox";
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from "react";

class PlayerForm extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                name: '',
                teamName: '',
                bio: '',
                teamId: ''
            };
            this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        }

    handleChange(name, event) {
        this.setState({[name]: event.target.value});
        console.log(this.state);
    }

    nextStep(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get values via this.refs
        var player = {
            id: uuid(),
            name: this.state.name,
            teamName: this.state.teamName,
            bio: this.state.bio,
            teamId: this.state.teamId
         };

         postDataTest(player);
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-6">
                <div className="panel">
                    <div className="panel-heading">
                        <h1>Add Player</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div className="panel-body">
                        <form className="form-horizontal">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label className="control-label">Name</label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" ref="name" defaultValue={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'name')}/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label className="control-label">Team Name</label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" ref="teamName" defaultValue={this.state.teamName} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'teamName')}/>
                            </div>
                            <TeamSelectBox state={this.state.teamId} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'teamId')}/>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label className="control-label">Bio</label>
                                <input type="textarea" className="form-control" ref="bio" defaultValue={this.state.bio} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'bio')}/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="bs-component">
                                 <button className="btn btn-md btn-default btn-block" onClick={this.nextStep}>Save &amp; Continue</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    }
}

module.exports = PlayerForm;
```

Answer (score 4):

`setState` doesn't mutate the state immediately and hence you must make use of `callback in setState` to log the updated value

```
handleChange(name, event) {
    this.setState({[name]: event.target.value}, function() {
            console.log(this.state);
    });

}
```

Also you did not bind the `nextStep` function. You should do that in the constructor or any other way you prefer

```js
class PlayerForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                name: '',
                teamName: '',
                bio: '',
                teamId: ''
            };
            this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
            this.nextStep = this.nextStep.bind(this);
        }

    handleChange(name, event) {
        this.setState({[name]: event.target.value});
        console.log(this.state);
    }

    nextStep(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get values via this.refs
        var player = {
            id: "9879",
            name: this.state.name,
            teamName: this.state.teamName,
            bio: this.state.bio,
            teamId: this.state.teamId
         };

         postDataTest(player);
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-6">
                <div className="panel">
                    <div className="panel-heading">
                        <h1>Add Player</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div className="panel-body">
                        <form className="form-horizontal">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label className="control-label">Name</label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" ref="name" defaultValue={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'name')}/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label className="control-label">Team Name</label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" ref="teamName" defaultValue={this.state.teamName} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'teamName')}/>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label className="control-label">Bio</label>
                                <input type="textarea" className="form-control" ref="bio" defaultValue={this.state.bio} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'bio')}/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="bs-component">
                                 <button className="btn btn-md btn-default btn-block" onClick={this.nextStep}>Save &amp; Continue</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<PlayerForm/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: get exactly the same error

Comment: It's when I click submit I get 'state is null' I can't see what you've changed in that code compared to mine

Comment: I have added the console.log(this.state) within a setState callback function', Also you need to bing nextStep function

Comment: Check my updated answer

Comment: can you explain why I had to bind the function in my constructor? Thank you!

Comment: because your nextStep function makes use of this.state and hence here `this` must refer to the context of your react class but since you don't bind it, `this` refers the context of the function iteself and hence state is not availabe